# python cross platform download all the files(not all needed so unwanted)

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

Hi I want to download linux version package in windows env.(install on offline linux-server)

I used the command:

```
pip download --only-binary=:all: --platform linux_x86_64 --python-version 36 hyperopt
```

to download package hyperopt and its dependencies to install it on linux env offline, I restrict python version to be 3.6, which is the python version on linux

However it seems downloaded all the hyperopt package it could get, which I suspect is not needed

Any way I can only download the specific package and dependencies that I could install and use in the currenct python version(3.6.13)??

[image: see the pic for details]

Comment: `hyperopt` doesn't provide `linux_x86_64` wheels, it only provides universal wheels: https://pypi.org/project/hyperopt/#files. Another dependency, `future`, [provides only sources](https://pypi.org/project/future/#files) and you forbade to download it. As you can see cross-platform download doesn't really work. My advice: run an emulator, install a target Linux and Python 3.6 in it, and do `pip3.6 download hyperopt`

Comment: pip download --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: --no-binary=:none: hyperopt; this works; but I don't know why. the future package has wheel files. Virtual Machine is not easy to setup and eat up some memory. So I will turn to it unless there is no other way @phd

Answer (score -1):

```
pip download --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: --no-binary=:none: hyperopt
```

this works, I downloaded all the files I needed to install hyperopt in linux offline but I don't know why, it seems the only difference is the platform from linux to manylinux

here is the result screen shot
[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The message is "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement networkx>=2.2 (from hyperopt) (from versions: 1.9rc1, 1.9, 1.9.1, 1.10rc2, 1.11rc2, 1.11)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for networkx>=2.2 (from hyperopt)"

Comment: With `pip3.11` the message is "ERROR: Cannot install hyperopt==0.1.1, hyperopt==0.1.2, hyperopt==0.2, hyperopt==0.2.1, hyperopt==0.2.2, hyperopt==0.2.3, hyperopt==0.2.4, hyperopt==0.2.5, hyperopt==0.2.6 and hyperopt==0.2.7 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies."

Comment: I don't know, I created an brand new py 3.6.13 env with anaconda and download hyperopt as my first package, may be you already have some packages which have conflict with some packages included? or your python version is not 3.6.13? I think I downloaded under python 3.8 is also failed. Maybe that is helpful for you